# Save InkCanvas strokes without using SaveFileDialog (UWP)

Tags: c#, uwp, inkcanvas

In my UWP C# app I'm trying to save the strokes of an InkCanvas in a way that the user should be able to load the file and continue editing the strokes, is it possible to do this without asking the user to choose a location but rather by saving the file to a default location?

Thanks in advance

Comment: See [File access permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions)

Comment: Are the files saved in the local folder of the app accessible if the app is reopened or do they get cancelled when the app is closed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a file in the AppData Local folder of your app and read it when necessary. I suggest using this code to create the file:

```
Windows.Storage.StorageFolder storageFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
Windows.Storage.StorageFile file = await storageFolder.CreateFileAsync("sample.gif", Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
```

And this one to write the strokes on it:

```
Windows.Storage.CachedFileManager.DeferUpdates(file);
IRandomAccessStream stream = await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);
using (IOutputStream outputStream = stream.GetOutputStreamAt(0)) {
   await inkCanvas.InkPresenter.StrokeContainer.SaveAsync(outputStream);
   await outputStream.FlushAsync();
}
stream.Dispose();

Windows.Storage.Provider.FileUpdateStatus status = await Windows.Storage.CachedFileManager.CompleteUpdatesAsync(file);

if (status == Windows.Storage.Provider.FileUpdateStatus.Complete) {
     // File saved
} else {
     // File NOT saved
}
```